# Unable to upload a file in login flow

Tags: visual-workflow, fileupload, loginflow

Is there a known issue with file upload in flow login?

Because, *I don't have problems in upload a file with the same flow attached to a record page*, but when is inside a login flow the same flow is unable to upload any file.

I use a file upload component for upload the file inside the flow. I used also a lightning:fileUpload component in aura component with flow but have the same results.

[image: Image of the flow login when I try to upload a file]

Seems there are no security problems in fact the same user can upload a file in the record page with the same flow.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

*how to reproduce the error:*

I tried this in two orgs, create a partner user and assign to them a login flow to be launched when he accesses to the partner site.

The login flow has a file upload component or an aura component with a lightning:fileUpload component, in my case the fileUpload will upload a file in the contact record associated to the partner user.

When you try to upload a file with this partner user an error will occur.

I tried the same flow in the page record contact of the partner user and it works fine, so it is not a problem of access and permissions. And the user is logged in so there is not a problem with guest users' accessibility

**EDIT 2**

In the browser console nothing gets printed and also in the apex debug with all fine nothing loads.

I found a workaround for this; but maybe someone can find a better solution.

Comment: Check if a user license for the Login Flow matches the profile license that you want to connect to the login flow. Also you could try to Create a Custom Login Flow with Visualforce.

Comment: HI @VitaliiDehnerys thanks for your gentle feedback. 
Unfortunately, it is not the case, in fact the login flow starts with the partner profile as intended and all works fine, the partner can access the contact record and change fields, but cannot attach any file in the flow, I dont think it's a problem of permissions and profiles

Comment: Do you see anything in the debug log?

Comment: @Wiidialga18 you can post the workaround as an answer so its more visible for anyone else having same issue. Multiple answers are acceptable on a question if you or someone else has a better solution later on

Answer (score 1):

Just create a html input tag:

```html
          <input
            type="file"
            class="slds-file-selector__input slds-assistive-text"
            accept="image/png"
            id="file-upload-input-front"
            aria-labelledby="file-selector-primary-label-105 file-selector-secondary-label106"
            onchange="{!c.onChangeInputFront}"
              />
```

to retrieve the file via controller, do:

```js
const inputFront = document.getElementById("file-upload-input-front");

    for (const file of inputFront.files) {
        // do your things
        console.log(file);
        helper.uploadHelper(component, file);
       }
```